# How can I run Ghost in Docker with the google/node-runtime image?

Tags: node.js, docker, ghost-blog, boot2docker

I'm very new to Docker, Ghost and node really, so excuse any blatant ignorance here.

I'm trying to set up a Docker image/container for Ghost based on the `google/nodejs-runtime` image, but can't connect to the server when I run via Docker.

A few details: I'm on OS X, so using I'm boot2docker. I'm running Ghost as a npm module, configured to use port 8080 because that's what `google/nodejs-runtime` expects. This configuration runs fine outside of Docker when I use `npm start`. I also tried a simple "Hello, World" Express app on port 8080 which works from within Docker.

My directory structure looks like this:

- my_app

  - content/
  - Dockerfile
  - ghost_config.js
  - package.json
  - server.js

#### `package.json`

```js
{
  "name": "my_app",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "ghost": "0.5.2",
    "express": "3.x"
  }
}
```

#### `Dockerfile`

```
FROM google/nodejs-runtime
```

#### `ghost_config.js`

I changed all occurrences of port 2368 to 8080.

#### `server.js`

```js
// This Ghost server works with npm start, but not with Docker
var ghost = require('ghost');
var path = require('path');

ghost({
  config: path.join(__dirname, 'ghost_config.js')
}).then(function (ghostServer) {
  ghostServer.start();
});

// This "Hello World" app works in Docker
// var express = require('express');
// var app = express();

// app.get('/', function(req, res) {
//   res.send('Hello World');
// });

// var server = app.listen(8080, function() {
//   console.log('Listening on port %d', server.address().port);
// });
```

I build my Docker image with `docker build -t my_app .`, then run it with `docker run -p 8080 my_app`, which prints this to the console:

```
> my_app@ start /app
> node server.js

Migrations: Up to date at version 003
Ghost is running in development... 
Listening on 127.0.0.1:8080 
Url configured as: http://localhost:8080 
Ctrl+C to shut down
```

`docker ps` outputs:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                     NAMES
4f4c7027f62f        my_app:latest   "/nodejs/bin/npm sta   23 hours ago        Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:49165->8080/tcp   pensive_lovelace
```

And `boot2docker ip` outputs:

```
The VM's Host only interface IP address is: 192.168.59.103
```

So I point my browser at: 192.168.59.103:49165 and get nothing, an no output in the Docker logs. Like I said above, running the "Hello World" app in the same `server.js` works fine.

Everything looks correct to me. The *only* odd thing that I see is that sqlite3 fails in `npm install` during `docker build`:

```
[sqlite3] Command failed: 
module.js:356
  Module._extensions[extension](this, filename);
                               ^
Error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found 

...

node-pre-gyp ERR! Testing pre-built binary failed, attempting to source compile
```

but the source compile appears to succeed just fine.

I hope I'm just doing something silly here.

Comment: It has helped me a few times to ssh into boot2docker and use curl to determine whether I'm dealing with a docker issue or a virtualbox/boot2docker issue.

Comment: Thanks. I ssh'ed into boot2docker and still can't connect to the node server with curl - I get a "Connection reset by peer" error. However when I `nsenter` into my container I can connect on port 8080, so at least I can see that Ghost is running. Seems like progress.

Answer (score 3):

In your ghost config, change the related server host to `0.0.0.0` instead of `127.0.0.1`:

```
server: {
  host: '0.0.0.0',
  ...
}
```

PS: for the SQLite error. Try this Dockerfile:

```
FROM phusion/baseimage:latest

# Set correct environment variables.
ENV HOME /root

# Regenerate SSH host keys. baseimage-docker does not contain any, so you
# have to do that yourself. You may also comment out this instruction; the
# init system will auto-generate one during boot.
RUN /etc/my_init.d/00_regen_ssh_host_keys.sh

# Use baseimage-docker's init system.
CMD ["/sbin/my_init"]

# ...put your own build instructions here...
# Install Node.js and npm
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | sudo bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

# Copy Project Files
RUN mkdir /root/webapp
WORKDIR /root/webapp

COPY app /root/webapp/app
COPY package.json /root/webapp/
RUN npm install

# Add runit service for Node.js app
RUN mkdir /etc/service/webapp
ADD deploy/runit/webapp.sh /etc/service/webapp/run
RUN chmod +x /etc/service/webapp/run

# Add syslog-ng Logentries config file
ADD deploy/syslog-ng/logentries.conf /etc/syslog-ng/conf.d/logentries.conf

# Expose Ghost port
EXPOSE 2368

# Clean up APT when done.
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
```

Note I used `phusion/baseimage` instead of `google/nodejs-runtime` and installed node.js & npm with:

```
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | sudo bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Dockerfile, you need this command `EXPOSE 8080`.
But that **only** makes that port accessible outside the Docker container.  When you run a container from that image you need to 'map' that port.  For example:

`$ docker run -d -t -p 80:8080 <imagename>`

The `-p 80:8080` directs port '8080' in the container to port '80' on the outside when it is running.

> The syntax always confuses me (I think it is backwards).

Comment: I will try this as soon as I can, but what I don't understand is why the hello world app works under the exact same configuration.

Comment: About to try this out, and just read the docs on `EXPOSE`. I don't think this will work because the docs say: "Note that EXPOSE only works for inter-container links. It doesn't make ports accessible from the host. To expose ports to the host, at runtime, use the -p flag."